# Bootstrap 4 Column Card overlapping

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

I am trying to put 4 cards in one row. When I put 2 cards, there is equal spacing. But when I put the third card in the same row, it overlaps the other despite using the same code. I tried changing the value to no avail. How do I go about resolving this without using custom css?

Comment: Remove second row class div then try

Comment: @HiteshKansagara What? If I remove it then it won't be in the same row anymore. What I want is cards in the same row

Comment: first div with class row that maintain it in same row

Comment: have you tried as i have said?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <h4>Recently sold items</h4>
    </div>
      <div class="row">

        <div clas="col-lg-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



       <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      </div>

    
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anu but this time it will bring the column to the next row, making it not aligned in the same row.

Comment: grid system is based on 12 grids per row. So it may be due to your grid is exceeding the 12 grid per row. Probably adjust the grid size of each card?

Answer (score 0):

The first of the 3 card cols has a typo: `clas=` instead of `class=`.

https://www.codeply.com/go/fl6AA76Io0

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <h4>Recently sold items</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        ..
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        ..
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        ..
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        ..
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @xxfirexx Did this work? --- accept an answer please